# SLD for dot density

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, sld, web-gis

I am trying to find, or get help creating, an SLD to render dot density symbolization for a polygon shapefile for an online GIS display - in this case WorldMap. The dataset is county level US Census of Agriculture data for cotton production in 1860 (tables and shapefiles from NHGIS). I am able to make a fine looking map in ArcGIS but the default styling for WorldMap is simply fill and line styles. One can however upload custom SLDs. I have no experience creating these in XML but am keen to try my hand at it. Any advice (or examples) on custom styling for dot density symbology?

While the dot density symbolization in Arc is great I can't export the underlying SLD with Arc 10.2.

If anyone knows of a plug-in that works with this build (and 64-bit Windows 7) that would be great.

As for QGIS I can't find a dot density symbology option beside the random dot generator in ftool which I actually can't get to work with my data.

Perhaps someone has some advice on the QGIS angle?

Comment: I think you should focus this question on something specific that you have tried with a single product, and tell us precisely what you tried and where you got stuck with that.